# Check duplicates name ignore entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to insert entry in my database. But i can add same entry multiple time and i wanna that whenever i submit same entry in input type then message will show "[Nickname already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTLAT.png) "

```html
<div> 
 <form>
  <div>name <input  type="text" name="na"/></div>
  <div>marks1 <input  type="text" name="m1"/></div>
  <div>marks2<input  type="text" name="m2"/></div>
  <div>marks3 <input  type="text" name="m3"/></div>
  <div> <input  type="submit" name="save" value="save"/></div>
 </form>
</div>
```

And Here is my php code:-

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['save'])){
    $na=$_GET['na'];
    $m1=$_GET['m1'];
    $m2=$_GET['m2'];
    $m3=$_GET['m3'];
    $query="insert into student(name,marks1,marks2,marks3)  values('$na','$m1','$m2','$m3')";
    mysqli_query($connect,$query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Put a [`UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) constraint and/or do a `SELECT` before your `INSERT` checking if the username already exists.

Comment: Make use of mysql unique index -> catch the error related to duplicate entry -> display message.

Comment: @ishegg can you share code sample?

Comment: @frz3993  can you share code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Make a unique column in database for example unique name for every student. So when you enter new record first check it that either it is present in the database or not. If its there then you can show error to user

For example you can set a unique constraint like this

[image]

Comment: The _UNIQUE_ constaint will not do all the job. He will have to catch a potential MySQL error caused by the _unique_ and return that information to its view.

Comment: @Zain Farooq i have already tried this. But not working. if entry already exist in database then message will show like this https://i.imgur.com/Xhmpwqq.png

Comment: Do you want live validation?

Answer (score 0):

Do a select before inserting in your base to check if the username already exists.

For your input message showing that the username already exists you can use a hidden paragraph:`<p id="informationText" hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>`

Then once your select request has returned that the tuple already exists do an ajax query to show up this paragraph: `$('#informationText').removeAttr('hidden');`

That's a simple way, there is other better way to do that you can do some research about `JavaScript Form Validation`

**FIRST EDIT**

Here is a code sample:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['save'] ) ){
    $na=$_GET['na'];
    $m1=$_GET['m1'];
    $m2=$_GET['m2'];
    $m3=$_GET['m3'];

    $query  = "select * from student where name = ? ";
    $result = mysqli_query( $connect,$query, array( &$na ) );
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );

    if (count($row) > 0) {
      echo "<script>$('#informationText').text = "Username already exists";$('#informationText').removeAttr('hidden');</script>";
    } else {
      $query="insert into student(name,marks1,marks2,marks3)  values('$na','$m1','$m2','$m3')";
      mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but a code sample would be great!

Comment: If you're going to add a code sample, don't you think you should create your own rather than plagiarize the non-working code of another answer?  Especially the insert query that doesn't even attempt to use a prepared statement...

Comment: My apologies, the insert statement was the OP's code.  Nevertheless, you should show your own working code that demonstrates best practices (to the best of your ability).

Comment: I had no working code on me. I just provided something to show him how to know if an username already exists and how to do an ajax request that will unhide the information text.